# Eclipse, best way to build shared library?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

I am rather new with C++ and using eclipse.

I have a **Native C++ Static Library** with a C++/CLI Wrapper in Visual Studio 2012.

Now I am building the Native C++ code in Linux with **Eclipse** (Juno Service Release 2) and **GCC 4.2.4.**

I created a **Shared Library Empty Project in Eclipse** and added all my .h and .cpp files, and let Eclipse do the building. However I got the error

```
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I added the **-fPIC** flag in Project->Settings->GCC C++ Compiler-> Miscellaneous-> Other Flags.

I don't know anyone proficient using Linux/Eclipse so I am not sure I took the best path.

Is there a best/"more correct" way to build a shared library than the way I just described?
Are there any issues to the approach I took?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `-fPIC` is the right thing to do, you should be fine.

Shared libraries need to be relocated when loaded (by `ldd`) and there are two main approaches: load-time relocation and Position Independent Code (PIC), with the latter being mainstream in modern solutions and architectures.

Comment: And regarding using Eclipse as I did? Allowing it to create its makefile and all, that should be fine too? Or it would be better if I create a makefile myself and create for example a "Makefile Project with Existing Code"?

Comment: I think it is fine to use Eclipse's 'Shared Library' project. If you are comfortable with Makefile/s then it is easier to manage certain aspects directly, but you didn't mention any specific complications (apart from -fPIC) in the question, so I think you should proceed with Eclipse in the meanwhile. Further, google for "building a shared library with Eclipse" I just did, and there were a number of good pages that came up.